Asus Prime X670-P compatibility with ubuntu
Does Motherboard :Asus Prime X670-P and GPU: GIGABYTE Nvidia GeForce RTX 4090 AERO OC 2024 compatible with ubuntu

Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "Shopping or Hardware Recommendations" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of opinion based questions.   All we can suggest is you boot a Ubuntu system in Try mode
